# Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer when trying to get dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My python looks like below

salary[salary['JobTitle'].value_counts()=='1']

Where salary is my dataframe which reads a csv without errors.

What I want is to get a dataframe where salary['JobTitle'].value_counts()=='1'.

In other words I want all records wherever Jobtitle appears only once in the dataframe

I get the following error when executing the above code in Jupyter notebook.

Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Thank you your help in advance.

Don

Answer (score 0):

Because [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) return counts of column for compare original column is necessary use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), also change string `'1'` to `1` for compare number `1`:

```
salary[salary['JobTitle'].map(salary['JobTitle'].value_counts())==1]
```